# Is there such a thing as nullptr (or equivalent) in modern C standards?

Tags: c, c17

I included a check for `nullptr` in a line of C code. The compiler (gcc) complained when using `-std=c17` as well as `-std=gnu17`.

Is there such a thing as nullptr (or equivalent) in modern C standards? (C11, C17)

If not, then why?

Comment: Yes. It’s `NULL`.

Comment: @user3840170 Does `NULL` in C differ significantly from `nullptr` in C++? I thought that `NULL` was just something which was defined to be or set to be `0`. Maybe I am mistaken about that however? (Whereas you can only assign `nullptr` to a pointer type in C++.)

Comment: Technically, `NULL` is an integer of value `0` casted to type `void*`, so you cannot normally assign `NULL` to non-pointer variables (I mean, you can, but you would have a type mismatch, and the compiler may or may not complain about that).

Comment: [The `NULL` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL) *may* be expanded to the integer literal `0`. *Or* it may be expanded to the pointer `((void *) 0)`. *Or* anything else corresponding to a null-pointer on the specific target platform. It's implementation defined. It is however guaranteed to always be compatible with all pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "Or anything else corresponding to a null-pointer on the specific target platform."---I think your wording here is vague and overbroad. It must be an integer constant expression with value `0` or the same cast to `void *`.

Comment: Not by me, but I was able to find the answer to your question in literally seconds by consulting the Standards document. If you do not have them, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) shows where they can be found.

Comment: @WeatherVane The standards documents, and other references, give details of *what*. They do not often give explanations as to *why*. Perhaps I should have included this. I will edit my question so that you will surely be satisfied.

Comment: As I said, it was not me who was dissatisfied. Sorry I have literally nothing else to do but try to find a helpful reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, C still uses `NULL` for a null pointer.

C++ needs a dedicated null pointer literal because it has overloading and template type deduction. These features get confused by `NULL`, which expands to `0` (or something like that) in C++. However, the risk of such confusion in C is small (maybe `_Generic` can get confused by this), and in addition, C can use `(void*)0` for a null pointer, which mitigates this risk even more.

Comment: Side note: It is safe to use `NULL` in C code while using `nullptr` in C++ code. Those two languages are different, and you should not try to compile C code with a C++ compiler, and vice versa. Madness lies in the direction where bilingual code is sought. (Only exception are headers for C libraries which can and should be made bilingual using the `extern 'C' {` construct).

Answer (score 5):

[ISO C 23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3047.pdf) now has `nullptr`, as well as the `nullptr_t` type. The [proposal](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3042.htm) that introduced it has some rationale.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to C++'s `nullptr` is C's `NULL`. Which [may be](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/NULL)

> - an integer constant expression with the value ​0​,
> - an integer constant expression with the value 0 cast to the type `void*`.
>
> A null pointer constant may be converted to any pointer type; such conversion results in the null pointer value of that type.

The formal C17 specifications state that the `stddef.h` header defines `NULL` "which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant." (7.19)
A *null pointer constant* is defined as follows (6.3.2.3)

> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant.) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
> 4. Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type. Any two null
>    pointers shall compare equal.

Note that this makes the following program ambiguous, as `NULL` could be an integer constant expression (accepted by the function) or of the type `void*` (not accepted by the function).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printInt(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}

int main(void)
{
    printInt(NULL);
}
```

[Which is why `nullptr` was introduced in C++11.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Null_pointer_constant) For C, having no function overloading or type deduction, this is less of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A null pointer in C is a pointer object pointing at "null". You can turn a pointer into a null pointer by assigning it to a *null pointer constant*. Valid null pointer constants are `0` and `(void*)0`. The macro `NULL` is guaranteed to be a null pointer constant.

The internal representation of the pointer then becomes a "null pointer", which could in theory point at an address different from zero on some exotic system. Similarly, `NULL` could in theory expand to something different from zero in old, pre-standard C.

When creating C++, Bjarne Stroustrup found all of this to be needlessly complex and decided that "NULL is 0" (source: https://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null). Notably C++ was created long before the first standardization of C, so his arguments are less relevant to standard C than they were to pre-standard C.

For more info about null pointers vs NULL in C, see [What's the difference between null pointers and NULL?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278657)